# z-index property marked as invalid because of bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have below markup and CSS that works fine when bootstrap is not used in my application. When i link bootstrap with my application z-index property of my "ddlSelect" class will not be applied on hyperlink.

```css
.divcols {
  color: #333 !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 2px;
}
.ddlSelect {
  background: url(../Images/Classic/Icons/dropdwn-img.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1100px !important;
  left: -7px;
  right: -17px;
  top: 3px;
  margin: 0 -2px 0 -15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divcols">
  <label for="txtDocPersonID">Doctor</label>
  <input class="ui-autocomplete-input valid" id="txtDocPersonID" name="txtDocPersonID" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">
  <a tabindex="-1" title="Show All Items" class="ddlSelect"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

z-index is not defined in pixel. try changing it to:

```
z-index: 1100;
```